# Creating Two Different Data Types for Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I desire to make a header of table in the columns containing integer data type for giving number each data sequentially and string data type for the header. The table illustrated below

| No | ReferenceNumber | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Transactions Reporting |  |  |
| for the Period of Q4 in 2023 |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| 1 | 159 | -510 |
| 2 | 159 | -512 |
| 3 | 160 | -523 |

Previously, the table was given like this one

| No | ReferenceNumber | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 159 | -510 |
| 2 | 160 | -523 |
| 3 | 159 | -512 |

However, with these queries below

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
No int identity(1,1),
ReferenceNumber varchar(255),
Amount varchar(255))

Insert Into Table1
select cast(RefNo as varchar(255)), cast(Amount as varchar(255))
from anothertable

SELECT * 
into #FirstTempTable
FROM Table 1

SELECT 
CAST('Transactions Reporting' as int) as No,
'' as ReferenceNumber,
'' as Amount
into #SecondTempTable

SELECT 
cast('for the Period of Q4 in ' as int) + cast(year(getdate()) as int) as No,
'' as ReferenceNumber,
'' as Amount
into #ThirdTempTable

SELECT 
cast('' as int) as No,
'' as ReferenceNumber,
'' as Amount
into #FourthTempTable

SELECT * FROM #SecondTempTable
union all
SELECT * FROM #ThirdTempTable
union all
SELECT * FROM #FourthTempTable
union all 
SELECT * FROM #FirstTempTable
```

I acquired the error result below

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NO' to data type int.

I know there is an unmatched data type, but with int identity it's matched for solving the unordered data. Please support for obtaining desired data like the first table display.

Big thanks for your helps

Comment: Did you try to debug and identify the problem query ?

Comment: Yes, but I want to try creating conditions for different types, like if the data type is int identity(1,1) it should be 1, etc, then if the data type is string it should be for the header.

Comment: `cast('for the Period of Q4 in ' as int)` i have a very hard time to see that sql server can cast that text to an INT. What do you think?

Comment: I know it's not matched, but it's my best effort I think. We can do this by changing int in the CREATE TABLE query to varchar(255), but I can't get the ordered number from 1 to n for sorting data

Comment: why not cast things to nvarchar(100) instead? then you should be able to union it. But you still need to fix the sorting

Comment: You cannot mix and match datatypes within the same column in a union. If your first table contains an int in the first column and the subsequent tables, strings, you have to convert the int to a string. The alternative, which it looks like you tried to do is convert everything else to an int. But clearly, you can't do that because "No" is not an integer

Comment: Seems like this is a matter for your presentation layer, such as tablixes in SQL Server Reporting Services or your other favourite reporting environment.

Comment: are there any ways for getting 1 to n number to order the numbe of data if the data type is string ? because i have only one way to order using int identity

Comment: What I would do is introduce a new column across all your datasets which is a global ordering integer. For the header data rows, just hard code 1, 2, and the for the actual data, do a row number starting at 3, ordered by your `No` field. Then order everything by the new pure integer column, and simply don't select it in the output (unless you want it in your results)

Comment: Could you illustrate that using query ? I didn't get it that

Comment: Can in the morning; on my phone right now. I'll check in on this if nobody takes a stab at it before then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```sql
select *
into #data
from (
    VALUES  (1, 159, -510)
    ,   (2, 160, -523)
    ,   (3, 159, -512)
) t (No,ReferenceNumber,Amount)


select header, referencenumber, amount
from (
    select -10 as sort, N'Transactions Reporting' as header, null as referencenumber, null as amount
    union all
    select -9, concat(N'for the Period of Q4 in ', year(getdate())), null, null
    union all
    select no, cast(no as nvarchar(100)), referencenumber, amount
    from #data
    ) x
order by sort
```

The trick is to create a sort field. I usually use negative numbers for simplicity, but whatever goes.

The second thing is that all corresponding columns in the union should have same datatype, otherwise the server will try to cast around things. This is why i cast(no as nvarchar(100))

Output:

| header | referencenumber | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Transactions Reporting | NULL | NULL |
| for the Period of Q4 in 2023 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 159 | -510 |
| 2 | 160 | -523 |
| 3 | 159 | -512 |

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to answer as well since I was thinking about this, and my approach was slightly different.

The main difference is instead of using arbitrarily small numbers for the header rows and relying on `No` being greater than those chosen numbers, I'm explicitly setting the order of each header row, and attaching a new `row_number`, offset by the number of header rows (in this case, 3)

So these are the header rows (going from 1 to 3)

```
select 1, 'Transactions Reporting', null, null union all
select 2, concat('for the period of Q4 in ', year(getdate())), null, null union all
select 3, null, null, null union all
```

And here is the unioned data (starting at 4):

```
select
    Sort = row_number() over (order by No) + 3,
    No = cast(no as varchar(255)),
    RefNo, 
    Amount
from #Data
```

So put all together it looks like this:

```
drop table if exists #data
select No = 1, RefNo = 159, Amount = -510 into #data
union all select 2, 160, -523
union all select 3, 159, -512 

;with src (Sort, No, RefNo, Amount) as
(
    select 1, 'Transactions Reporting', null, null union all
    select 2, concat('for the period of Q4 in ', year(getdate())), null, null union all
    select 3, null, null, null union all
    select
        Sort = row_number() over (order by No) + 3,
        No = cast(no as varchar(255)),
        RefNo, 
        Amount
    from #Data
)

select No, RefNo, Amount
from src
```

Both Siggemannen's approach and mine do basically the same thing. The difference is his is a bit more lightweight because it relies on the values in `#data.No` for the ordering (at the probably negligible risk of `No` containing negative values less than -10) and mine avoids that, except at the cost of having to do a `row_number` and sorting the data.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer